# Sendgrid API and User Subscription Logic within a Rails 4 Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825465/best-practices-for-sending-email-to-lots-of-recipients-rails-sendgrid) and it seems that I could avoid using the delayed jobs gem which would be preferred.

Basis of the application:

- an outage notification system for a cable company
- When an outage occurs at a property (or properties), a ticket gets created
- There are over 2000 properties, so properties are split into 8 categories based on business type and geographic location
- a user can subscribe to 8 potential categories
- only certain users can create tickets.
- when a ticket is created, updated, or closed, a user will get an email/sms notification if they are subscribed to one of the categories that the property is in.

**The issue: emails are being sent when a ticket is created/updated closed, but there will eventually be 300+ subscribed users receiving emails. I currently have about 15 test users and when a ticket is modified, it seems 15 separate requests are being sent every time: this is quite slow in the browser (ie, the ticket modifier may wait 10+ seconds after the create/update/close button is clicked), but bearable. As more and more users subscribe, this slowness will not be tolerable.**

[Here](https://gist.github.com/ornerymoose/595617c75795652d395ffdefed6b3f91) is the ticket controller in full if you'd like to check it out: I realize it is fairly repetitive and doesn't follow DRY principles, and could certainly be refactored.

I'm confused on how to implement (from the linked SO post above)

```
headers["X-SMTPAPI"] = { :to => array_of_recipients }.to_json
```

since the categorical logic is in the controller, but the `app/mailers/user_notifier.rb` is where the email methods are defined, and isn't that where `headers["X-SMTPAPI"] = { :to => array_of_recipients }.to_json` would have to go?

Line 219 of `tickets_controller.rb` is below.

```
def grab_all_sub_emails
    @all_users = Subscription.where.not(name: '')
    @sub_emails = @all_users.includes(:categories).map { |user| user.slice(:phone_number, :name).merge(categories: user.categories.map(&:name))}
end
```

Any input on how I need to modify my logic/implement `headers["X-SMTPAPI"] = { :to => array_of_recipients }.to_json` to speed up the emailing process would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over `@emails_for_email` and call `UserNotifier` on each since you're already setting the `:to` key in the `X-SMTPAPI` header.

Just pass `array_of_recipients` to the UserNotifier, set it as a header:

```rb
def ticket_created(array_of_recipients)
  ...
  headers["X-SMTPAPI"] = { :to => array_of_recipients }.to_json
  ...
  mail
end
```

And SenGrid will read the `X-SMTPAPI` header, read the `:to` key and deliver the message to all the recipients.

---

May I recommend using the [sendgrid-ruby](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby) gem and perhaps store the templates in SendGrid?

Comment: @milligraf thank you for the reply. So I removed that iteration as it was unnecessary and just call `UserNotifier` once. As for the `X-SMTPAPI` header, I'm still a bit confused. So that doesn't need to be called anywhere explicitly in my code? Or do I need to reference it in the mailer `user_notifier.rb` ?

Comment: Ahhh I see now! Interesting, didn't realize it was so straight forward. Really appreciate your help. After updating/creating/closing a ticket, there is way less delay on the submit button. Tyvm! (And the array of email recipients is showing up correctly as an array in the server log).